# At command with installed programs

Tags: command-line, bash, 15.04

I am trying to test `at` in `15.04`. So far, nothing has been printed to terminal or any programs run

```
echo "test" | at now + 1 min

ls -l | at now + 1 min
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the output from commands issued to `at`, you need to have a correctly configured `sendmail` on your system. Otherwise, the output is discarded.

If you just want to test that the command is successfully run, try choosing a command with some residual effect:

```
echo 'touch /tmp/huzzah_it_works' | at now
```

Then look in `/tmp/` to see if the file was created.

Comment: do you have any other methods of running an interactive program from terminal after a time period? I tried `sleep` with `nohup` but I get similar results

Comment: I ended up using `sleep 5 | echo "test"`